# IE8 and div overlap when hiding/showing divs

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, overlap, css

I use some DIV to create blocks with data inside.
I've set them to "inline-block" because I want the div to adjust his width to the content.

IE8 adjust his width to my content but I have a weird problem.

If you go to this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/GvMW8/ and click to the first or second link, you can see that divs are overlapping.

If you go to this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hhpRP/1/ and do the same operation, it works!

The only difference between these two fiddles are the 'id' attribute of the main divs.

I don't understand why I have this problem, but can you tell me how to make it works with the inline-block display AND a div id?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a little IE8 bug.

Check out http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/fjqUc/

I added an extra class for the div around bigBlock and made it display: inline-block.
I also shortened your javascript.

This seemed enough to make IE8 listen :)

Comment: Thanks for this fast response!